# Understanding do notation for simple Reader monad: a <- (*2), b <- (+10), return (a+b)

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where  
    return x = \_ -> x  
    h >>= f = \w -> f (h w) w  

import Control.Monad.Instances  

addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff = do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)  
    return (a+b)
```

I'm trying to understand this monad by unwiding the do notation, because I think the do notation hides what happens.

If I understood correctly, this is what happens:

```
(*2) >>= (\a -> (+10) >>= (\b -> return (a+b)))
```

Now, if we take the rule for `>>=`, we must understand `(*2)` as `h` and `(\a -> (+10) >>= (\b -> return (a+b)))` as `f`. Applying `h` to `w` is easy, let's just say it is `2w` (I don't know if `2w` is valid in haskell but just for reasoning lets keep it this way. Now we have to apply `f` to `h w` or `2w`. Well, `f` simply returns `(+10) >>= (\b -> return (a+b))` for an specific `a`, which is `2w` in our case, so `f (hw)` is `(+10) >>= (\b -> return (2w+b))`. We must first get what happens to `(+10) >>= (\b -> return (2w + b))` before finally applying it to `w`.

Now we reidentify `(+10) >>= (\b -> return (2w + b))` with our rule, so `h` is `+10` and `f` is `(\b -> return (2w + b))`. Let's first do `h w`. We get `w + 10`. Now we need to apply `f` to `h w`. We get `(return (2w + w + 10))`.

So `(return (2w + w + 10))` is what we need to apply to `w` in the first `>>=` that we were tyring to uwind. But I'm totally lost and I don't know what happened.

Am I thinking in the rigth way? This is so confusing. Is there a better way to think of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're forgetting that operator `>>=` doesn't return just `f (h w) w`, but rather `\w -> f (h w) w`. That is, it returns a function, not a number.

By substituting it incorrectly you lost the outermost parameter `w`, so it's no wonder it remains free in your final expression.

To do this correctly, you have to substitute function bodies for their calls completely, without dropping stuff.

If you substitute the outermost `>>=`, you will get:

```
(*2) >>= (\a -> ...) 
==
\w -> (\a -> ...) (w*2) w
```

Then, if you substitute the innermost `>>=`, you get:

```
\a -> (+10) >>= (\b -> return (a+b))
==
\a -> \w1 -> (\b -> return (a+b)) (w1 + 10) w1
```

Note that I use `w1` instead of `w`. This is to avoid name collisions later on when I combine the substitutions, because these two `w`s come from two different lambda abstractions, so they're different variables.

Finally, substitute the `return`:

```
return (a+b)
==
\_ -> a+b
```

Now insert this last substitution into the previous one:

```
\a -> (+10) >>= (\b -> return (a+b))
==
\a -> \w1 -> (\b -> return (a+b)) (w1 + 10) w1
==
\a -> \w1 -> (\b -> \_ -> a+b) (w1 + 10) w1
```

And finally insert this into the very first substitution:

```
(*2) >>= (\a -> ...) 
==
\w -> (\a -> ...) (w*2) w
==
\w -> (\a -> \w1 -> (\b -> \_ -> a+b) (w1 + 10) w1) (w*2) w
```

And now that all substitutions are compete, we can reduce. Start with applying the innermost lambda `\b -> ...`:

```
\w -> (\a -> \w1 -> (\_ -> a+w1+10) w1) (w*2) w
```

Now apply the new innermost lambda `\_ -> ...`:

```
\w -> (\a -> \w1 -> a+w1+10) (w*2) w
```

Now apply `\a -> ...`:

```
\w -> (\w1 -> w*2+w1+10) w
```

And finally apply the only remaining lambda `\w1 -> ...`:

```
\w -> w*2+w+10
```

And voila! The whole function reduces to `\w -> (w*2) + (w+10)`, completely as expected.

Comment: I understood. Bow how on earth could the do notation explain all this? I understand the do notation as simply a way of writing a chained `>>=` application in an easier to read way, BUT I don't know how to write a do notation without first writing the chained `>>=` version, so I see no point in it.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs if that's your real question you should update the OP to ask if explicitly. But how to "read" `do` notation depends on the specific monad being used - precisely because it desugars to uses of `>>=`. But in general, `a <- m` means "run the computation `m`, and assign the result to the variable `a`", except it does this in a functionally pure way. In the case of this function monad, it means that,  in the function we are building, we start by multiplying the input by 2, and use `a` to denote the result.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Perhaps this monad isn't the most useful one, but you might think of do-notation in this monad as something that lets you access an implicit (immutable) value. When you "run" the line `x <- f`, you apply `f` to the implicit value, and bind the result to `x`. So, instead of `foo v = let {x = f v ; y = g v ; z = h v } in x+y+z` we can make `v` implicit and write `foo = do {x <- f; y <- g; z <- h; return (x+y+z) }`. You can write the last code without thinking of what the underlying `>>=` does.

Answer (score 2):

First, we write out the implicit argument in your definition explicitly,

```
addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff = do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)  
    return (a+b)
  =
addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff x = ( do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)  
    return (a+b) ) x
  =
  ....
```

Then, with

```
    return x  =  const x  
    (f =<< h) w  =  f (h w) w      -- (f =<< h)  =  (h >>= f)
```

it should be easier to follow and substitute the definitions, line for line:

```
  ....
  =
    ( (*2) >>= (\a ->                     -- (h >>= f)  =
       (+10) >>= (\b -> 
         const (a+b) ) ) ) x
  =
    ( (\a ->                              --   =   (f =<< h)
       (+10) >>= (\b ->
         const (a+b) ) ) =<< (*2) ) x     -- (f =<< h) w  =
  =
      (\a ->
       (+10) >>= (\b ->
         const (a+b) ) )  ( (*2) x) x     --   =  f (h w) w 
  =
    ( let a = (*2) x in                   -- parameter binding
       (+10) >>= (\b ->                   
         const (a+b) ) )            x
  =
      let a = (*2) x in                   -- float the let 
      ((\b ->
         const (a+b) ) =<< (+10) )  x     -- swap the >>=
  =
      let a = (*2) x in
       (\b ->                             -- (f =<< h) w  =
         const (a+b) )  ( (+10) x)  x     --   =  f (h w) w
  =
      let a = (*2) x in
       (let b = (+10) x in                -- application
          const (a+b) )             x
  =
      let a = (*2)  x in                  -- do a <- (*2)
      let b = (+10) x in                  --    b <- (+10)
      const (a+b)   x                     --    return (a+b)
```

The essence of reader monad is application to same argument shared between all calls.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, each function call on the right-hand side of the `<-` is given an additional argument, which you can think of as the argument to `addStuff` itself.

Take

```
addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff = do  
    a <- (*2)  
    b <- (+10)  
    return (a+b)
```

and turn it into

```
addStuff :: Int -> Int  
addStuff x = let a = (*2) x
                 b = (+10) x
             in (a+b)
```

It looks a little less "strange" if you use the `MonadReader` instance for `(->) r`, which provides `ask` as a way to get direct access to the implicit value.

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

addStuff :: Int -> Int
addStuff = do
  x <- ask   -- ask is literally just id in this case
  let a = x * 2
  let b = x + 10
  return (a + b)
```

Comment: might I suggest turning the "and turn it into `addStuff x = let { a = (*2) x ;
                 b = (+10) x }
             in ` **`(a+b)`** into `addStuff x = { let a = (*2) x ;
                 b = (+10) x }
             in ` **`const (a+b) x`** ..?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that my transformation was a strict desugaring and replacement of the `Monad` methods with their definitions. `const (a+b) x` just reduces to `a + b` anyway, so I'd prefer to leave it as it is.